# How to ping (native) from a yocto recipe

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I want to ping inside a yocto recipe from the build-machine if a server is reachable (for signing etc. ...).

According yocto documentation the `DEPENDS` variable should handle this by adding e.g. `iputils-native`.
The problem is, that iputils has no native implementation. Finally there is no ping command at the recipe's sysroot.

Are there alternative methods to get this done?

Comment: You could use the build machine's ping, by adding `HOSTTOOLS += " ping"` to local.conf. Also, make sure to enable network access for the step that uses ping (if's after `fetch`, by adding something like `do_install[network] = "1"` to the recipe (with using the correct step, that requires network access.) Although it is somewhat against Yocto's self-contained nature, I think it is safe to assume that ping is available on all build hosts.

Comment: Just tried - it works as you described. If this is a fine solution is questionable but a quick check which tools are already part of ```HOSTTOOLS``` has shown, that it really should not matter, when ping is one aditional tool.

Comment: Another thing that came to my mind is that you could use `CONNECTIVITY_CHECK_URIS` variable in local.conf or distro.conf. This takes a list of URIs that are checked at the start of building. If any of the addresses is unavailable, the build fails quick. This would be a more Yocto-like solution.